# Shortcut to Windows Security Protection history

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, shortcuts, file-shortcut

Is there a (text) shortcut to Protection history in Windows Security? The menu is located at

Windows Security (or paste `%windir%\explorer.exe windowsdefender:` into Start menu) >
Virus & threat protection >
Current threats >
Allowed threats >
Protection history

Another format would be like `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System`. It's for [instructions](https://www.reddit.com/r/MouseAccel/comments/i49h2f/windows_antimalware_fix/?).

Answer (score 5):

There is a way:

```
explorer windowsdefender://History
```

But this is plucked from uwp resources and is not a documented action, at least I could not find an explicit source from MS. The list of Windows Security pages is given below, found [here](https://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=62&topic=31147&start=960#21):

```
explorer windowsdefender://Threat               # Virus & Threat Protection
explorer windowsdefender://ThreatSettings       # Virus & Threat Protection Settings
explorer windowsdefender://Account              # Account Protection
explorer windowsdefender://Network              # Firewall & network Protection
explorer windowsdefender://Hardware             # Device Security
explorer windowsdefender://DeviceSecurity       # Device Security
explorer windowsdefender://Family               # Family Option
explorer windowsdefender://AppBrowser           # App & Browser Control
explorer windowsdefender://Settings             # Manage Notifications
explorer windowsdefender://History              # Protection History
explorer windowsdefender://RansomwareProtection # Ransomware Protection
explorer windowsdefender://ProtectedFolders     # Ransomware Protection
explorer windowsdefender://SecurityProcessor    # Security Processor Details
explorer windowsdefender://SecurityProcessorTroubleshooting #  Security Processor Troubleshooting
explorer windowsdefender://SmartScreenPua       # Smart Screen (Reputation Based Protection)
explorer windowsdefender://AccountProtection    # Account Protection
explorer windowsdefender://ExploitProtection    # Exploit Protection
explorer windowsdefender://exclusions           # exclusions
explorer windowsdefender://fullscan             # Select fullscan
explorer windowsdefender://quickscan            # Start quickscan
```

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has made it much more difficult to view protection history. To open Defender, use a shortcut to `ms-settings:windowsdefender` ...  but then as you state you  must manually open *Virus & threat protection*, which then runs *SecHealthUI.exe* in "C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_cw5n1h2txyewy". Trying to open that executable directly fails. *sigh*. And then, following the thread to finally open *Protection History* initially displays "No recent actions'" and one must *wait* for history to be shown.

However: **You can quickly view current threats in quarantine** [in a CMD prompt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-antivirus/command-line-arguments-microsoft-defender-antivirus), [with Powershell](https://theitbros.com/managing-windows-defender-using-powershell/) or [with third party tools](https://www.ghacks.net/2020/03/30/nirsofts-latest-tool-helps-you-manage-windows-defender-threats-in-bulk/), though.

To see quarantined items from CMD:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *cmd*, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to get a CMD prompt as Administrator.
- Enter(copy and paste) the following:

  "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" -Restore -ListAll
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see all files in quarantine.

To view quarantine in PowerShell, use the following commandlets:

```
Get-MpThreat 
Get-MpThreatDetection
```

Nirsoft's [WinDefThreatsView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/windows_defender_threats_view.html) is perhaps the quickest way to view quarntine.

Regrettably, *this is not a complete answer to your question*, as I know of no shortcut to display full *Protection History*.

Comment: Tbh it's a bit over my head and seems more complicated than I'd put in the tutorial. But thank you for the effort! And nice formatting!